# Enable default syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Since most questions on this site won't be language specific, but virtually all answers will contain code, the tag-based syntax-highlighting approach [recently adopted by SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) won't work for this site. However I think that syntax highlighting would be worthwhile to have nonetheless.

I thus propose that the old mode of syntax highlighting be enabled for this site, where all the code samples are highlighted using prettify's default "guess" mode.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 2):

I agree. Perhaps we could turn on syntax highlighting with no hints only when the [language-agnostic](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag is used. I have always preferred to be specific by using this tag over letting users assume it's implied by the lack of a language tag.

Comment: I'm not fond of having a tag that applies to almost every question. Though that's a different discussion.

Comment: @sepp2k It might be the case now, but we've only been going on 2 days. It's one of the many things time will tell.

Answer (score 2):

Given that SO's syntax highlighter is *notoriously bad* for plenty of source code I'd rather prefer no syntax highlighting to broken one.

If there was a way to hint a specific language to use that might be an option. But prettify's own detection is (imho) worse than no highlighting at all. And »Supports all C-like, Bash-like, and XML-like languages« was definitely not enough on SO; it may well be not enough here.

Comment: They are using Google's prettify now, aren't they? If so there *is* a way to hint. **Added:** Looks like it's not done yet. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082/2509 and linked.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like syntax highlighting. Here's my idea:

We could use:

```
<meta language="C++" />

Here's some code:

    #include <iostream>

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << "Skynet imported for the 42nd time.";
        return(0);
    }

As you can see, it pretty much sucks.
```

Or something similar to distinguish between languages. It reverts to guessing if `<meta language="C++" />` isn't specified.

Comment: @S.Mark That doesn't seem to work...

Comment: sorry, its only works on Stack Overflow and meta, I don't know why. ref - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019